# mod_deflate for css and js

Tags: javascript, css, mod-deflate

I'm using mod_deflate to compress my web pages but I see that only the HTML is compressed no compression for the css.

```
Documents (1 file) 4 KB (18 KB uncompressed)
    http://localhost/web/ 4 KB (18 KB uncompressed)
Images (16 files) 96 KB
Objects (0 files) 
Scripts (2 files) 26 KB (73 KB uncompressed)
    http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js 24 KB (70 KB uncompressed)
    http://localhost/web/js.js 2 KB
 Style Sheets (1 file) 6 KB
    http://localhost/web/css/style.css 6 KB
 Total 132 KB (192 KB uncompressed)
```

My .htaccess looks like:

```
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
</ifmodule>
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should this maybe be a serverfault question?

Comment: *How* do you use mod_deflate to compress your HTML documents?

Comment: # BEGIN GZIP

<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript

</ifmodule>

# END GZIP

Comment: @mohamed87: Where does it say that your HTML document is compressed?

Comment: using Web Developer -> information -> view document size

Comment: @mohamed87: Ah, my mistake. Now I see that every “uncompressed” means it actually is compressed.

Comment: @mohamed87: But what is your *http://localhost/web/*? Is it a static HTML file?

Comment: no it's dynamic and this is the root of one of the websites that I locally develop. for this it's a php page index.php which includes another dynamic file like home.php or category.php?cat=foo&pg=bar
But here it's ok with the main document as it is compressed. the problem concerns the css and js excluding the jQuery as it comes compressed from it's CDN

Comment: @mohamed87: Maybe PHP is already compressing the data (see for example [`ob_gzhandler`](http://php.net/ob_gzhandler)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I don't know how, this finally worked and the css became 2KB instead of 6KB.
Thanks everybody for your help.